# Difference between File System and Storage system on DB2 UDB server

Tags: database, filesystems, db2, relational

We are having a DB2 database on a server.  We are repeatedly getting file system full error which goes away when DBA temporarily increase file system capacity.

When we have database installed on , isn't the data stored on disk or storage system ?  What is role of file system in a relational database installed on a server ( on AIX OS ).  I am trying to understand how does a file system differs from storage system on a server or say DB2 database server.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that DB2 is automatically increasing the size of the file(s) it's using as tablespace containers for your database, and it only complains when there is no free space left in the underlying file system(s). At that point, the DBA enlarges the file system (which, by the way, is not necessarily a temporary action), and DB2 is happy again because it can continue to increase the size of its tablespace container file(s) as needed to accommodate the incoming data.

The file system holds the files that DB2 uses for database storage, but DBAs also have the option of assigning unmounted, "raw" disk devices/volumes to serve as containers for DB2 tablespaces. The original appeal of using raw storage for databases was largely a response to the performance hits previously imposed by file system buffering and journaling, both of which are already carried out by DB2. However, DB2 LUW eventually gained the smarts to allocate and use files for database storage without enabling any of the slow, redundant file I/O options, so the leading choice these days is to use files instead of raw storage.

On your DB2 server, you can use the df command in AIX to proactively check the remaining free space for each of your mounted file systems, including the file systems that contain your DB2 tablespaces.